# Is it possible to check when a transaction has been sent?

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions, txpool, validators

Is it? I don't mean the date-time of the 1 confirmation, but when a person has actually **submitted** a transaction to the blockchain or rather the transaction pool?

Or is it the case that the date-time of when a transaction is **sent** is, in fact, equal to date-time when the 1st confirmation is made? For until it's been confirmated by at least 1 validator, a transaction deemed non-existend. Correct?

Comment: This question is too general, in theory anything's possible. If you refer to a specific blockchain, please say which.

Comment: It is not possible in Ethereum like blockchains, the submission date isn't recorded as part of the transaction. If you have more doubts just create new questions.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, on a blockchain that implements this - it's possible.

On Ethereum (and forks) it's **impossible**, since the info of transmission time isn't recorded in the transaction.

The only way to know that on Ethereum is to track the mempool and record the time each transaction first appears.

Comment: you've repeated what I've stated

Comment: on what blockhains then that is possible?

Comment: I don't know any blockchain that can do that. I know that Ethereum and forks don't. You're not referring to any specific blockchain, so in principal the answer is - yes, it's possible.

Comment: Then how do you know that "it depends on blockchain"?

Comment: Because each blockchain is a different implementation and it's possible to implement this. But.. since this is Ethereum stack exchange, I initially assumed you meant in Ethereum or one of its forks.

Comment: Then why did you say "it depends on blockchain" if we're on Ethereum stack exchange?

Comment: Initially I didn't. After seeing your comment "on what blockhains then that is possible" I realised you don't necessarily mean Ethereum, therefor edited my answer to match your question. Any more questions?

Comment: Yes, I still have many questions.